# Jest async test always times out when used with mongodb-memory-server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, async-await, jestjs

I'm using mongodb-memory-server package and am having some trouble getting my async jest tests to run properly. I have a beforeAll that connects to a memory mongo database:

```
beforeAll(async () => await connect());
```

then I have an async test:

```
it("creates a new user", async () => {
      const userObj = {
        firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
        lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
        phoneNumber: "+14444444444",
        uid: faker.random.uuid(),
      };
      const userRes = await axios.post(routeUrl + "/", userObj);
      const createdUser = userRes.data.user;
      expect(createdUser._id).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

the issue is that my test always times out when it is both async and includes an endpoint that modifies some data using the mongodb-memory-server. If I were to remove the async and put the logic after `userRes` in a .then, the test passes. If I keep the async/await but wrap the code inside the test in a 1000ms async timeout, the test passes. Any thoughts on why the test is timing out in this current format shown above?

Here is an example of a passing version of the test:

```
it("creates a new user", () => {
      const userObj = {
        firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
        lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
        phoneNumber: "+14444444444",
        uid: faker.random.uuid(),
      };
      axios.post(routeUrl + "/", userObj).then(
         userRes => {
             const createdUser = userRes.data.user;
             expect(createdUser._id).toBeTruthy();
         }
      );
  });
```

Comment: Can you share the passing version? It may be that your version with the `.then` isn't returning the promise and so jest isn't waiting for it to "pass the test". You can also confirm the checks run by adding a https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber check.

Comment: @dcwither just added an example of a passing test

Comment: Why aren't you mocking the mongodb stuff with [jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) and use something like for the application router testing with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest?

Comment: My interpretation was that this is an end to end/integration test, and so I didn't comment on that, but if this is intended to be a unit test, then Max's question points to some valuable resources.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your passing `.then` test isn't actually finishing. In the `async` test, the await ensures that the promise finishes before the async function resolves.

In your passing `.then` test, it's actually not running the check before the test "passes". In order to fix this, and get an accurate test, you could make the following changes:

```js
it("creates a new user", () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const userObj = {
    firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
    lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
    phoneNumber: "+14444444444",
    uid: faker.random.uuid(),
  };
  return axios.post(routeUrl + "/", userObj).then((userRes) => {
    const createdUser = userRes.data.user;
    expect(createdUser._id).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

You should find that this times out as well.

This change (adding the `return` and the `expect.assertions`) ensures that the promise resolves before the test finishes. You can look at Jest's [async example](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) for more details on how this works.

Using [`expect.assertions(number)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber) is really useful to ensure async tests are actually testing what you intend to test.

In order to resolve the timeout (if the issue is that 1000ms is too little), you can set the timeout explicitly using the [3rd argument to `it/test`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testname-fn-timeout).

```js
it("creates a new user", () => {...}, 2000)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ['done' callback](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) along with a [testTimeout](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testtimeout-number).

Comment: Your answer contains a link that is pointing back to itself, perhaps you should write a bit of code to demonstrate what's the answer to the question.